# How to build on OTA mechanism with a JEOS

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, buildroot, ota, over-the-air

I developped a software, based on a raspberry pi, some RF433 sensors and built with buildroot.
So I have an up and running platform doing the stuff it is intended for.
My question is how to keep my system up to date, with new versions, etc...

Is there any guidance, or framework, or tools defined in linux to do that ?
For exemple, within buildroot, if I replace the wpa_supplicant executable with an other package, how to push the new version of my image to the raspberry pi (automatically or not), without having to get the sdcard out, rewrite it, and replug it... ?

Answer (score 1):

Buildroot has two packages that perform over the air updates of the whole system: swupdate and rauc.

Actually using them is still a lot of effort though, because a lot depends on what kind of system you deploy it on (choice of bootloader, boot media, partitioning, ...). So you have to figure out how to integrate this tool into an OTA update mechanism.